Graph with an exponential number of paths
I am looking at the language $F$ containing all $G,v_0,v_1$ s.t.:

$G$ is undirected
$G=(V,E)$
$v_0,v_1\in V$
$|V|=n$
There are $2^n$ paths between $v_0$ and $v_1$

I would like to prove that $F\notin NP$. Intuitively, I know the witness is too large to hold. But I don't know how to formally state this? What will I be able to contradict? Is this problem considered $NEXP$-hard?

Are these simple paths or non-simple (= walks)? The number of walks can be computed in polynomial-time by matrix powering, hence in the latter case, your language is in P (or even in DET). In the former case, you can count the number of paths in #P, hence your language is in PP or in $C_=P$, depending on whether “$2^n$ paths” means “at least $2^n$ paths” or “exactly $2^n$ paths”.

Either way it is not NEXP-hard unless something very bad happens.

What I had in mind was a criss-crossing set of paths: $u\rightarrow v_i$ for $i\in{1,2}$ and then $v_i\rightarrow w$ and then $w\rightarrow w_i$ for $i\in {1,2}$ again and so on. This would result in $2^n$ (give or less) possible paths, all are simple (maybe, $2^\frac{n}{2}$), but still counts for my problem, so I can inquire about $2^\frac{n}{2}$ instead.

Please [edit] your post to clarify what you are asking, based on the feedback here.
